# SOM Algorithm Matlab HELP

Tags: user-interface, matlab, som

I'm trying to pass a txt file to som_read_data from a GUI......i created a function that takes a txt file from the GUI and then passes it to som_read_data..but i'm getting some errors...here are a list of some of the errors.....any one with ideas?

```
??? Error using ==> ftell
Invalid file identifier.  Use fopen to generate a valid file identifier.

Error in ==> som_read_data at 169
  fpos1 = ftell(fid); c1 = 0;      % read first non-comment line

Error in ==> prog_som at 3
sD = som_read_data(m);
```

Answer (score 2):

The error says that your file identifier may not be valid. Did you check?

You get a file identifier (`fid` in your function `som_read_data`) by calling `fid=fopen(fileName)`, where `fileName` is the name of your file if it's in the current directory, or the file name including path name otherwise.

To debug, you may want to call `[fid,message] = fopen(fileName)` and check whether `message` is empty. If it's not, there has been an error opening the file, and consequently, `fid` is not a valid file identifier.

**EDIT** You may want to look at what `message` says. My bet is that it is something like 'file not found', either because the file is not on the path, or because you miss the extension.

**EDIT2** Look through som_read_data to find which function is returning `fid` before it is used in line 169. If the line says `fid = fopen(m)`, then you should pass a filename to `som_read_data`, i..e call `som_read_data(B)`.

Comment: the line of code used in my GUI to read the file is get the file is:

[filename, pathname] = uigetfile( ...
{'*.m;*.fig;*.mat;*.mdl','MATLAB Files (*.m,*.fig,*.mat,*.mdl)';
   '*.m',  'M-files (*.m)'; ...
   '*.fig','Figures (*.fig)'; ...
   '*.mat','MAT-files (*.mat)'; ...
   '*.mdl','Models (*.mdl)'; ...
   '*.*',  'All Files (*.*)'}, ...
   'Pick a file');

B = [filename,pathname];
m = textread(B);
x = prog_som(m)

The variable "m" is now passed onto Prog_som.m as input.....or is dis wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The error indicates that either you didn't open a file first, or [FOPEN](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/fopen.html) was not able to open the file correctly. If the value of the returned file identifier is `-1` after a call to [FOPEN](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/fopen.html), it indicates that an error occurred (such as trying to open a non-existent file).

**EDIT:**

Based on your comment, you are building the path to your file incorrectly. You should create `B` as follows:

```
B = [pathname,filename];  %# Append filename to the end of pathname
%# Or
B = fullfile(pathname,filename);  %# In case pathname doesn't have a file
                                  %#   separator (`\` or '/') on the end
```

You had the order reversed (`B = [filename,pathname];`), which would give you an invalid file path and thus an invalid file identifier `fid` when trying to open the file with [FOPEN](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/fopen.html).

Comment: the line of code used in my GUI to read the file is get the file is: [filename, pathname] = uigetfile( ... {'*.m;*.fig;*.mat;*.mdl','MATLAB Files (.m,.fig,.mat,.mdl)'; '*.m', 'M-files (*.m)'; ... '*.fig','Figures (*.fig)'; ... '*.mat','MAT-files (*.mat)'; ... '*.mdl','Models (*.mdl)'; ... '*.*', 'All Files (.)'}, ... 'Pick a file'); B = [filename,pathname]; m = textread(B); x = prog_som(m) The variable "m" is now passed onto Prog_som.m as input.....or is dis wrong?

Comment: @Tim: I updated my answer to address a bug in the code in your comment.

Comment: I tried that but there is still an error......I think i'm lacking a command after uigetfile but before textread??

Comment: @Tim: If your intent is to pass a *file name* to `prog_som`, then you should pass the file path `B`. In the code in your comment, you are reading the text from the file `B` and passing *that text* to prog_som.

Comment: @Tim: Just pass `B` to `prog_som` instead of `m`. Then, inside `prog_som`, make sure you pass the file path along to `som_read_data`, where your error is stemming from.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are using [som_read_data](http://www.cis.hut.fi/somtoolbox/package/docs2/som_read_data.html) function from [SOMTOOLBOX](http://www.cis.hut.fi/projects/somtoolbox/). The function suppose to get data file name as argument. But you are read the file with textread into m variable and pass it to Prog_som.m, which pass it to som_read_data. I don't know if Prog_som.m does something with m-variable. Anyway try to pass B instead of m:

```
[filename, pathname] = uigetfile( ...
B = fullfile(pathname,filename);
x = prog_som(B);
```

Also make sure your file is in SOM_PAK format. You can find it's description in the comments inside som_read_data.m.

Comment: BTW, would you use normal English please?

Comment: ok....i'd like to generate comprehensive plot diagrams with my som algorithm.....how do i go about dat?..

Comment: This should be independent question. What exactly "comprehensive plot diagrams" do you need? Have you run 4 demos in the toolbox?

Comment: possible to get ur email...need to ask some other questions

Comment: i cn bt got lots of questions to ask...... prefer a conversation probably on msgr.....i cn drop my yahoo or hotmail addy if u dont mind....but if u insist on this site...its fine

Comment: Here is better, Others may help you as well.

Comment: hello yuk, i'm designing a GUI to implement som algorithm......and I want to provide a input box in which a user can specify factors like no of iterations,what distance metric to be used, type of neighbourhood function and initial and final values of neighborhood functions, ...what som toolbox files do i link diz input boxes to nd hw do i code it in matlab???

Comment: Hey....would really like to know what line of code(in wt M-file) in the som toolbox performs the iteration function as well as the line of code  for the neighborhood functions...i've been trying to get that for a while nw bt cant....i'd highly appreciate ur help!!!